# Using "the" before "load balancing"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

In this sentence, should I use **the** before **load balancing**? And I wanted to know whether I should use *done* or *performed* in this sentence?

> In this architecture, .... load balancing is done not only among cameras of a domain, but
> also among different domains.

Comment: Does your sentence start like _(The) load balancing [...]_, or is there something prior to it that you have not included here??

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh I wrote the exact sentence

Comment: _The_ shouldn't be inserted, as it is a general thing, and not something definitive to the architecture. Load balancing is performed on the VM instance I guess, so it should be _performed_ or _executed_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In this sentence, should I use the before load balancing?

“Load balancing” (technical jargon) is a phrasal gerund acting as a noun. As with any noun, the article depends on your intended meaning. Here you seem to be referring to a general practice (very common with gerunds), so it would take a zero article.

> And I wanted to know whether I should use done or performed in this sentence?

“to do” as a *main verb* is a generic substitute for a more specific verb that is understood from context, usually to avoid repetition. If that condition applies, feel free to use “do”. If there is any ambiguity, though, use a meaningful verb.

Comment: Although in many technical articles it is common to find operations such as "load balancing", "tuning" etc "performed" rather than "done". It's the vernacular of such texts.